# Why do I have 2 Firefox installations on the same PC?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, browser

I recently detected that, when some application opens a browser window, it opens a firefox installation that is different from my "normal" one (windows 10), i.e. the one that opens when I click on the FF icon on my task bar.

The differences are that the second (new, abnormal) one has a blue title bar, the normal one has a black title bar. I am not logged in on the blue one with firefox sync, all my plugins/bookmarks are missing and I cannot drag&drop tabs between the two versions. When I look at the "about" page, they show the same information though (Firefox Quantum, 68.0.1). It's also not the "private browsing" mode. See below screenshot of the two versions running at the same time.

[image]

I tried to set the default browser, but it shows only one version of firefox there.

In my apps control panel, I see only one installation. Right-clicking on the task bar icon and then on properties, shows the same executable as well.

If I open the "normal" one with the black title bar, it shows up in the Task manager as one main item with sub-items for the windows open. The blue one shows up as another main item with it's own sub-items. All of them refer in the properties to "c:\program files\Mozilla Firefox" as the path:

[image]

If I open additional windows/tabs on either the blue or black version, the sub-items increment accordingly on each task manager item. So it seems to be a real seperate executable that is running there.

Are those just different launch methods of the same browser executable? Or are those two different installations (such as a native program and a windows store app, I had that with skype once).

How do I avoid that external apps start a browser window that is different from my normal one that is started with the browser icon (i.e. manually)?

Comment: How many profile directories do you have?  “So it seems to be a real seperate executable that is running there.“ - No;  You likely have two profiles with a single installation directory. Multiple instances of the Firefox process is absolutely normal (it would happen if you had one profile but multiple Firefox windows).  It’s just how Firefox manages each tab

Comment: @Ramhound You are correct, it's a profile issue. I removed the faulty one and the external app asked me if I want to use the default one on the next start. Please submit as answer so I can approve.